# In Notepad++ replace all lines except ones that match to given expression, using regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

I saw here some answers that might help me if I'll combine them together but I can't seem to figure out how to do it properly.

Lets assume we have a following text file:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
[a]
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa[h]
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

[a]
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa[h]
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

Where:

- "a" means literally any character (or set of characters), including special symbols, unicode characters etc.
- "h" is a fixed latin character
- brackets mean brackets
- blank line is a blank line

Then:

- How do I keep only lines with [h] at the end replacing everything else with bank lines? (means carriage return remains)
- How do I keep the same lines but also remove [h]?

> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa[h]
>   
>   
>   
>   
>   aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa[h]

As title says, I guess what I need can be also described as: replace any line except the line that matches to the given expression.

Comment: Are you looking to do perform this within Notepad++ or an actual programming language?

Comment: Notepad++ is preferred, I could use programming language as last resort only. But anyway there is an answer already so...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find what:

```
^.*$(?<!\[h\])
```

Replace with nothing. Make sure to uncheck `. matches newline`.

How does it work?

```
^        # matches the beginning of a line (after the line break)
.*       # matches as many non-line-break characters as possible (an entire line)
$        # matches the end of a line (before the line break)
(?<!     # a negative lookbehind, if it's contents match left of the current
         # position, it causes the pattern to fail
  \[h\]  # match [h] literally
)        # end of lookbehind
```

Note that [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) are not part of the match. So `^.*$` simply makes sure that you are matching entire lines and not parts of them and neither multiple ones. The lookbehind then assures that the matched line has not ended with `[h]`.

You can then remove the `[h]` with an additional step:

Find what: `\[h\]$`

Replace with nothing.

**EDIT:** Due to the fact that the regex engine traverses the file from beginning to end and the fact that matches can never overlap, you can actually put both patterns into one:

```
^.*$(?<!\[h\])|\[h\]$
```

By the time an `[h]` at the end of the line is removed, the engine will not look at that line again, so you're only left with the lines that used to have an `[h]` at the end.